# Dynamic fields on insert/edit form

Tags: cakephp

let's say that i have 3 tables:

1. books
2. properties
3. book_properties

of course, i would like that when i want to insert new book (or update existing), to fill the form.

fields that exist on form have to be defined as records in table properties.

when i fill up those fields, data has to be saved in table book_properties.

can you help me by giving some advices and references, how to achieve that?

thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create 3 tables: books (id, author, title, etc.), properties (id, name) and **books_properties** (id, book_id, property_id, property_value). Notice that the third table must be named *books_properties*, not *book_property*. Then you will need to create models for the books and properties tables. See the manual [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together). Create correct assosiations. Books HasAndBelongsToMany Properties. If you use [cake console](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1522/Code-Generation-with-Bake) it will be easier to create models, controllers and views.